# Cannot deploy UWP app with ms-appinstaller

Tags: uwp, windows-10, appinstaller

I created my UWP app package, but ms-appinstaller shows me error when I try to install.

[image]

"Error in parsing the app package.", all files can be downloaded via browser

ms-appinstaller file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="http://uwplauncher.politcubes.ru/PolitCubes_x64.appinstaller"
    Version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2">
    <MainPackage
        Name="60c86cc0-5a17-46a6-a7f9-1c6eec38e089"
        Version="1.0.0.0"
        Publisher="CN=redfo"
        Uri="C:/Users/redfo/nginx-1.19.2/html/PolitCubes_1.0.0.0_x64_Test/PolitCubes_1.0.0.0_x64.msix"
        ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
    <Dependencies>
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            Version="2.2.27912.0"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://uwplauncher.politcubes.ru/PolitCubes_1.0.0.0_x64_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2.appx" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            Version="2.2.28604.0"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://uwplauncher.politcubes.ru/PolitCubes_1.0.0.0_x64_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2.appx" />
        <Package
            Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00"
            Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
            Version="14.0.27810.0"
            ProcessorArchitecture="x64"
            Uri="http://uwplauncher.politcubes.ru/PolitCubes_1.0.0.0_x64_Test/Dependencies/x64/Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.14.00.appx" />
    </Dependencies>
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

If I run .msix, then it install my app successfully.

(right window shows what my app already installed 'cause I installed it with .msix before my question)

upd1:

I set mime types , but this don't work

Comment: I'm a little confused about the ms-appinstaller? Do you mean you created an appinstaller file? And then you created a msix file, right? Could you please tell me how do you create the appinstaller file and how do you create the msix file?

Comment: I create package of UWP app to deploy on web server (enable autoupdate from server), it automatically create .appinstaller & .msixbundle/.msix files.

Comment: all details you can see in this issue (created by me):

https://github.com/microsoft/msix-packaging/issues/383

Comment: May I know how did you create the package? Using Visual Studio or Msix packaging tool?

Comment: Using VS, of course. All info in issue:

"Pack it in Visual Studio with self-signed cert and enable autoupdate for domain uwpdeploy.test.local"

Comment: So what is the file type that directly created by the Visual Studio? The packaging process should generate one type of installer- msix or appinstaller, not all of them. Did you package them twice to test?

Comment: It creates app directory with .msix/.msixbundle and .appinstaller in root directory. No, I didn't create package twice to test

Comment: The packaging process should not generate the .appinstaller in the root directory. The msix/msixbundle is the correct package. I'd suggest you just use the msix/msixbundle.

Comment: I try to set ms-source as .msix/.msixbunle in <a/>, but this don't work